# Find and replace in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am performing the min-max-scaler operation on a data frame which contains numeric columns, but if the within those numeric columns if any cell contains a string or null value then I am getting an exception.
To avoid that I think of converting the string or null cell to 0.
How to perform that?
my function:

```
def min_max_scaler(df_sub,col_names):
"""
import the following:
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

df_sub    : Expecting a subset of data frame in which every columns should be number fields
        (It contains all the columns on which you want to perform the operation)
example   : df_subset = df.filter(['latitude','longitude','order.id'], axis=1)
col_names : All column names of the subset
"""
    scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    scaled_df = scaler.fit_transform(df_sub)
    scaled_df = pd.DataFrame(scaled_df, columns=col_names)

    return scaled_df
```

Dataset :

```
day phone_calls received
7       180      NaN
8       8        NaN
9     -240       qbb
```

how to put the validation before executing this function.Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

find columns of `object` dtype:

```
obj_cols = df[col_names].columns[df[col_names].dtypes.eq('object')]
```

convert them to numeric dtypes, replacing NaN's with `0` (zero):

```
df[obj_cols] = df[obj_cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(0)
```

scale:

```
df[obj_cols] = scaler.fit_transform(df[obj_cols])
```

as a function:

```
def min_max_scaler(df_sub,col_names):
    scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    obj_cols = df_sub[col_names].columns[df_sub[col_names].dtypes.eq('object')]
    df_sub[obj_cols] = df_sub[obj_cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(0)

    return df_sub
```

Comment: And if It contains "string" value then how to replace it with 0?

Comment: @Sidhartha, it's already covered by `.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(0)` - it'll convert strings to NaN's and `.fillna(0)` will replace NaN's with zeros

Comment: I have updated the question, Do I need to add those three lines to the first of the function?